# How to start solving this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

How would you even begin this question? You could resort to a massive amount of equations using nodal or mesh analysis, but is there any faster way to go about solving it?
[image]

Comment: No effort to solve has been demonstrated.

Comment: "but is there any faster way to go about solving it? ", um...

Comment: Use Superposition and Thevenin . (Look out for wheatstone bridge configs ; not sure, but looks like there should be some. They'll simplify the job considerably)

Comment: If you want to solve it and don't care how I'd use Spice (LTSpice in my case).. I believe it would be faster. I do know that might not be answer you need but as a double check it's useful...

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to pick a reference node to be your ground. I'd suggest the one at the negative end of the two power supplies. There are a few series resistors you can combine, but aside from that, you're probably stuck with mesh equations. You could try making a Thevenin equivalent or doing a delta-wye transform somewhere, but I doubt it's worth the hassle. There's only seven mesh currents, and you can use Ohm's Law to get the top-left one.